# Changing *FLAGS in configure.ac vs. caching with subprojects

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, cflags

Say I wish to add a specific flag to `CFLAGS` within my `configure` script, that should propagate to all subprojects' `configure` scripts:

```
CFLAGS+=" -Dfoobar"
export CFLAGS
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([sub])
```

This works when `configure` is invoked trivially. As soon as one of the following happens:

1. `CFLAGS` is exported in the environment when `configure` is invoked
2. `CFLAGS` is set on `configure` command-line
3. caching is used (`configure -C`)

This approach no longer works. In the first two cases, the exported `CFLAGS` is simply ignored; and in the last one, `configure` fails with

> configure: error: `CFLAGS' was not set in the previous run

---

I have managed to get this working reliably by:

```
AM_CFLAGS+=" -Dfoobar"
export AM_CFLAGS
AC_SUBST([AM_CFLAGS]) # repeat this line in every configure.ac for each *FLAGS
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([sub])
```

Considering there are multiple subprojects, and multiple `*FLAGS` variables that may need to be set like this, this is half-way okay but still suboptimal. Is there a way to make this work by only hacking the top-level `configure.ac`?

Comment: What happens when you try to [define a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Defining-Variables) within the environment passed to `configure`?

Comment: @rubicks That works, but misses the point: I want my top-level `configure` to prepare and set the various `*FLAGS` for multiple subpackage `configure` invocations. And I need the `autoconf` facilities to check for compiler/linker options, etc. in order to prepare those flags. (Though you did get me thinking of manually invoking subpackage `configure`s from the top-level one, it just sounds dirty...)

Comment: CFLAGS is a user variable, and the maintainer should not be modifying it.  You are allowed to tweak AM_CFLAGS, (but flags of the form -Dfoo belong in AM_CPPFLAGS)

Comment: The original motivation involved setting mandatory flags (like using the gcc4-compatible c++ ABI) whilst `AM_*FLAGS` were being overridden in some 50+ makefiles in the project. While it would have been possible to fix each and every `target_*FLAGS` override to include the `AM_*FLAGS` and not override it, this was seen as much simpler, as the non-`AM_` `*FLAGS` are always included. An issue arises when the affected `FLAGS` variable is modified at `make`-time, as that overrides the configure-generated definition. Since this is a "mantainer=user" kind of project, it's not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate solution was to [*un-precious*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257795/can-you-un-precious-a-configure-variable-inverse-of-ac-arg-var) the affected variables:

Top-level configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([test], [0.1])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) # for ax_append_flag.m4
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])

AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_SED

# Modify the CFLAGS. AX_APPEND_FLAG makes sure not to add the flag if it's already there
AX_APPEND_FLAG([-Dtop-configure], [CFLAGS])

AC_DEFUN([AX_UNPRECIOUS], [
    m4_define([_AC_PRECIOUS_VARS], m4_bpatsubst(_AC_PRECIOUS_VARS, [$1
], []))
])
AX_UNPRECIOUS([CFLAGS])
export CFLAGS

AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([sub])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Behind the curtains, `CFLAGS` is never seen as precious and thus never cached or passed to sub-package `configure`s—they see it as an environment variable *exclusively*, and then cache it themselves in the common top-level `config.cache`.

This works very reliably, and improves upon my previous solution by allowing cached values even across top-level configure runs (and by being simpler).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally gotten this to work, except for caching across multiple top-level `configure` runs. The idea is to hack autoconf's internal variables to get the desired functionality, and it wasn't too hard:

- modify `CFLAGS`
- hack `ac_configure_args` to include the modified `CFLAGS` instead of any externally detected `CFLAGS`

This immediately solved problems 1. and 2. from the problem description (external `CFLAGS`). In order to fix caching, I had to:

- hack `ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_{set,value}` to contain `set` and the modified `CFLAGS`, respectively

This lead to two issues:

1. with caching, `./config.status --recheck` would perform the modification to CFLAGS again, even though this modification has already been cached, resulting in repeated flags. Doing the modification only if it hadn't been done resolved this issue.
2. when invoking the top-level configure with an existing `config.cache`, a corruption is unavoidable, because the `config.cache` consistency check is performed so early, it cannot be influenced. Only if we were to pass `CFLAGS` *including* the `configure`-modification on the command-line (or environment), would this check pass, no way around it. The only fix for this was to delete `config.cache` after all sub-packages have been configured. As caching during sub-package configuration still works, I found this acceptable.

Top-level `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([test], [0.1])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) # for ax_append_flag.m4
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])

AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_SED

# Modify the CFLAGS. AX_APPEND_FLAG makes sure not to add the flag if it's already there
AX_APPEND_FLAG([-Dtop-configure], [CFLAGS])

# Replace/add CFLAGS in/to ac_configure_args
AS_CASE([$ac_configure_args],
    [*CFLAGS=*], [ac_configure_args=`AS_ECHO "$ac_configure_args" | $SED ["s|CFLAGS=[^']*|CFLAGS=$CFLAGS|"]`],
    [AS_VAR_APPEND([ac_configure_args],[" 'CFLAGS=$CFLAGS'"])]
)

# Fix the cache vars
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=$CFLAGS

# exporting CFLAGS is not needed for sub-packages: they get CFLAGS from ac_configure_args

AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([sub])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT

AC_MSG_NOTICE([removing config.cache])
rm -f config.cache
```

Sub-level `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([test-sub], [0.1])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([../m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AX_APPEND_FLAG([-Dsub-configure], [CFLAGS])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The `Makefile`s only print the value of `$CFLAGS` in an `all-local` target.

Output looks like this:

```
$ autoconf && ./configure -C >/dev/null && make | grep CFLAGS # 1st run
sub CFLAGS: -g -O2 -Dtop-configure -Dsub-configure
top CFLAGS: -g -O2 -Dtop-configure
$ ./configure -C >/dev/null && make | grep CFLAGS # 2nd run
sub CFLAGS: -g -O2 -Dtop-configure -Dsub-configure
top CFLAGS: -g -O2 -Dtop-configure
$ touch configure.ac && make | grep CFLAGS # recheck run
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure -C CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Dtop-configure --no-create --no-recursion
sub CFLAGS: -g -O2 -Dtop-configure -Dsub-configure
top CFLAGS: -g -O2 -Dtop-configure
$ CFLAGS=-Dexternal ./configure -C >/dev/null && make | grep CFLAGS # 1st run
sub CFLAGS: -Dexternal -Dtop-configure -Dsub-configure
top CFLAGS: -Dexternal -Dtop-configure
$ CFLAGS=-Dexternal ./configure -C >/dev/null && make | grep CFLAGS # 2nd run
sub CFLAGS: -Dexternal -Dtop-configure -Dsub-configure
top CFLAGS: -Dexternal -Dtop-configure
$ touch configure.ac && make | grep CFLAGS # recheck run
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure -C CFLAGS=-Dexternal -Dtop-configure --no-create --no-recursion
sub CFLAGS: -Dexternal -Dtop-configure -Dsub-configure
top CFLAGS: -Dexternal -Dtop-configure
```