# Can you "un-precious" a configure variable (inverse of AC_ARG_VAR)?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

The [AC_ARG_VAR](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html#index-AC_005fARG_005fVAR-1030) macro declares a variable precious which has certain cache-checking implications.

Some configure macros declare certain variables precious, and I would like to undo that. For example, `AC_PROG_CC` will declare `CFLAGS` as precious, and I need to make it non-precious.

---

### Motivation

Doing this would allow me to modify `CFLAGS` in a top-level configure and allow sub-package configures to execute without clashing with cached `CFLAGS` value. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124337/changing-flags-in-configure-ac-vs-caching-with-subprojects) for more background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_UNPRECIOUS], [
    m4_define([_AC_PRECIOUS_VARS], m4_bpatsubst(_AC_PRECIOUS_VARS, [$1
], []))
])

AX_UNPRECIOUS([CFLAGS])
AX_UNPRECIOUS([CXXFLAGS])
...
```